# C++ cannot add to vector inside template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors

I'm learning about templates.

I have:

```
template<typename SQLObject>
std::vector<SQLObject> executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector(std::string _recordType,
                                                             std::string _sql,
                                                             int _rowCount)
{
    typename std::vector<SQLObject> v;

    if (_recordType == AppConstants::sSQLFieldObject)
    {
        for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
        {
            SQLFieldObject o;

            o.putFieldNumber(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
            [snip]
            v.push_back(o);
        }
    }

    if (_recordType == AppConstants::sSQLNotificationObject)
    {
        for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
        {
            SQLNotificationObject o;

             o.putNotificationID(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
             [snip]
             v.push_back(o);
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error on `v.push_back(o);` that states:

`no matching member function for call to 'push_back'`

I think it makes sense why, its fuzzy to me, since this is a typename determined at compile time?

Does this mean I have to implement my own `push_back()` function?

Is "C++ Templates The Complete Guide" by Vandevoorde and Josuttis @ 2003 still apply for C++11?

**UPDATE 1:** Consider this edit:

```
template<typename SQLObject>
std::vector<SQLObject> executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector(std::string _recordType,
                                                             std::string _sql,
                                                             int _rowCount)
{
    //typename std::vector<SQLObject> v;

    if (_recordType == AppConstants::sSQLFieldObject)
    {
        std::vector<SQLFieldObject> v;

        for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
        {
            SQLFieldObject o;

            o.putFieldNumber(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
            [snip]
            v.push_back(o);
        }

        return v;
    }

    if (_recordType == AppConstants::sSQLNotificationObject)
    {
        std::vector<SQLNotificationObject> v;

        for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
        {
            SQLNotificationObject o;

             o.putNotificationID(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
             [snip]
             v.push_back(o);
        }

        return v;
    }

    //return v;
}
```

I get compiler errors on both `return v;` like:

```
no viable conversion from 'vector<class SQLFieldObject>' to 'vector<class SQLNotificationObject>'

no viable conversion from 'vector<class SQLNotificationObject>' to 'vector<class SQLFieldObject>'
```

I'm calling this like:

```
std::vector<SQLFieldObject> _v = executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector<SQLFieldObject>    (AppConstants::sSQLFieldObject, getSQLToSelectFields(), rowCount);
```

and

```
std::vector<SQLNotificationObject> _v = executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector<SQLNotificationObject>(AppConstants::sSQLNotificationObject, getSQLToSelectNotifications(), rowCount);
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the use of templates, but rather with the fact that you are trying to add a `SQLNotificationObject` or a `SQLFieldObject` into a vector of `SQLObject`. Try writing the code without using templates, and you will see the same issue.

Comment: I think your SQLObject is a polymorphic type. In that case you need to use vector of pointers i.e. vector<SQLObject*>. This will allow you to store pointers of SQLFieldObject as well as pointers of SQLNotificationObject in the same vector.

Comment: @rockoder - I'm actually calling it twice and when called it is always the same type going into the vector. I updated again.

Comment: @Jason - That's not going to help. Function can have only one return type. executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector()'s return type is std::vector<SQLObject>. It cannot return std::vector<SQLFieldObject> or std::vector<SQLNotificationObject>. Hence you are getting error at the return statement.

Comment: @rockoder - Can we go a little further? I thought that was one of the benefits of templates that you could return different types like what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Jason - I got confused with the SQLObject as a polymorphic type. Looks like its just a type parameter. Don't use specific type within the function. Replace SQLFieldObject and SQLNotificationObject with SQLObject inside the function. Check out the sample program I wrote in the answers section.

Comment: For readability, you should not call your template parameter the same thing as an actual class  (I'm not sure whether or not you are doing that but it seems you might be, based on the names `SQLObject` and `SQLFieldObject`).

Comment: @matt. I'll replace with T for safety.

Comment: OK. Is `SQLObject` also the name of a class (and is that a base class of `SQLObject` and `SQLFieldObject`)?  Which template parameters do you plan to instantiate this function template with, besides `SQLObject` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb - no I just made it up instead of T. My hope was to create a local vector inside the function, same type as T and return it

Comment: The problem here is that you are using run time conditional statements (`if` statements) for compile time decision making. This doesn't work, because all branches of the `if` must compile, even if only one ever executes. Compile-time decision making can only be done with function overloading and template pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `v` is `std::vector<SQLObject>`. The type of `o` is `SQLFieldObject`. Unless there is an automatic way to cast an object of type `SQLFieldObject` to `SQLObject`,

```
v.push_back(o);
```

it is not an allowable operation.

**Update**

The errors associated with the updated code are:

The return type of `executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector` is `std::vector<SQLObject>`. The `return` statements return either `std::vector<SQLFieldObject>` or `std::vector<SQLNotificationObject>`. Well, the type of the objects being returned don't match with return type in the function signature.

Dealing with the templates a little bit more elegantly:

```
 // A template class that returns an appropriate string based on the
 // typename used to instantiate.
 template <typename SQLObject> struct RecordTypeChooser;

 // Specialization for returning the record type for SQLFieldObjects.
 template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLFieldObject>
 {
    static std::string getRecordType() { return AppConstants::sSQLFieldObject; }
 };

 // Specialization for returning the record type for SQLNotificationObjects.
 template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLNotificationObject>
 {
    static std::string getRecordType() { return AppConstants::sSQLNotificationObject; }
 };

 // A template class that constructs an object and returns it.
 // The object type is based on the typename used to instantiate.
 template <typename SQLObject> struct ObjectCreator;

 // Specialization for constructing SQLFieldObjects.
 template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLFieldObject>
 {
    static SQLFieldObject createObject()
    {
       SQLFieldObject o;
       o.putFieldNumber(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
       return o;
    }
 };

 // Specialization for constructing SQLNotificationObjects.
 template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLNotificationObject>
 {
    static SQLNotificationObject createObject()
    {
       SQLNotificationObject o;
       o.putNotificationID(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
       return o;
    }
 };



 template<typename SQLObject>
 std::vector<SQLObject> executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector(std::string _recordType,
                                                          std::string _sql,
                                                          int _rowCount)
 {
    typename std::vector<SQLObject> v;

    // Not sure whether you need this any more.
    if (_recordType == RecordTypeChooser<SQLObject>::getRecordType())
    {
       for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
       {
          v.push_back(ObjectCreator<SQLObject>::createObject());
       }
    }

    return v;
 }
```

**Update: Fully compiled and linked source**

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>

 struct SQLFieldObject {};
 struct SQLNotificationObject {};

 // A template class that returns an appropriate string based on the
 // typename used to instantiate.
 template <typename SQLObject> struct RecordTypeChooser;

 // Specialization for returning the record type for SQLFieldObjects.
 template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLFieldObject>
 {
    static std::string getRecordType() { return "SQLFieldObject"; }
 };

 // Specialization for returning the record type for SQLNotificationObjects.
 template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLNotificationObject>
 {
    static std::string getRecordType() { return "SQLNotificationObject"; }
 };

 // A template class that constructs an object and returns it.
 // The object type is based on the typename used to instantiate.
 template <typename SQLObject> struct ObjectCreator;

 // Specialization for constructing SQLFieldObjects.
 template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLFieldObject>
 {
    static SQLFieldObject createObject()
    {
       SQLFieldObject o;
       // o.putFieldNumber(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
       return o;
    }
 };

 // Specialization for constructing SQLNotificationObjects.
 template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLNotificationObject>
 {
    static SQLNotificationObject createObject()
    {
       SQLNotificationObject o;
       // o.putNotificationID(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
       return o;
    }
 };



 template<typename SQLObject>
 std::vector<SQLObject> executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector(std::string _recordType,
                                                          std::string _sql,
                                                          int _rowCount)
 {
    typename std::vector<SQLObject> v;

    // Not sure whether you need this any more.
    if (_recordType == RecordTypeChooser<SQLObject>::getRecordType())
    {
       for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
       {
          v.push_back(ObjectCreator<SQLObject>::createObject());
       }
    }

    return v;
 }


 void foo()
 {
    std::vector<SQLFieldObject> v1 = executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector<SQLFieldObject>("SQLFieldObject",
                                                                                       "",
                                                                                       10);

    std::vector<SQLNotificationObject> v2 = executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector<SQLNotificationObject>("SQLNotificationObject",
                                                                                       "",
                                                                                       10);
 }

 int main() {}
```

Comment: Can you consider the update in my description now? This is what I originally tried.

Comment: @Jason, I updated my answer to address the new errors and a refactored implementation of `executeSelectQueryReturnSQLVector` that should pose no more compiler problems.

Comment: Wow, let me review this. I do see at `template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLFieldObject>` a message: `explicit specialization of 'RecordTypeChooser' in class scope` Would one namespace it out?

Comment: @Jason I had forgotten to add `static` to the functions in the `ObjectCreator` classes. The answer is now updated.

Comment: I had added static there but I still see errors on `template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLFieldObject>` and `template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLNotificationObject>` and `template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLFieldObject>` and `template <> struct ObjectCreator<SQLNotificationObject>` that say `explicit specialization of 'RecordTypeChooser' in class scope
        template <> struct RecordTypeChooser<SQLFieldObject>` etc one for each of the statements I mention Not enough characters to paste each error

Answer (score 0):

The types in the vector and in the instances differ. Vector saves only the pristine classes (and cannot save children due to memory allocation issues otherwise). You may however store pointers to the classes. Consider this:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SQLObject> SQLObjectPtr;
typedef std::vector<SQLObjectPtr> SQLObjectPtrVector;

...
for(int r=0; r < _rowCount; r++)
{
    SQLFieldObjectPtr o(new SQLFieldObject);

    ...
    v.push_back(o);
}
```

Comment: Can you consider the update in my description now? This is what I originally tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    char b;
};

template<typename T>
vector<T> fun(char type)
{
    if (type == 'A')
    {
        vector<T> v;
        // generate objects of A and append to v
        return v;
    }
    else
    {
        vector<T> v;
        // generate objects of B and append to v
        return v;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<A> v = fun<A>('A');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me look at this because it looks very similar to what I am already doing. Let me look for differences between mine and yours.